# Mysql Grouping and Counting

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

i have a 3 Tables:

```
1 TableTraders
trader_id|Domain|
---------------------
1|google.com
2|yahoo.com
```

2 Table Counter_in

```
counter_time    counter_ip  counter_domain_id
    111111  222222  1
    111111  222224  2
    111111  222225  3
    111111  222232  2
    111111  222221  3
    111111  222223  4
    1111311     22223422    5



 3 Table Out Counter
counter_time    counter_ip  counter_domain_id
    111111  222222  1
    111111  222222  2
    111111  222222  3
    111111  222226  2
    111111  222221  3
    111111  222222  4
1309351485  2130708581  5
    1309351485  2130708581  4
    1309710116  2130706433  4
    1309351485  2130708581  1
1309710274  2130706433  1
```

Ok what i want todo is join the tables 1 , 2 , 3 and group them together, and count them.

```
trader_id|DOMAIN|IN|OUT
--------------------------
1|google.com|3|1
2|yahoo.com|1|2
```

I tried many things, but i get always wrong results. How do i join right the queries that i get results i want

**EDIT*

The query attempted:

```
SELECT traders.trader_id, traders.domain, COUNT( counter_in.counter_domain_id ) AS today_in, COUNT( counter_out.counter_domain_id ) AS today_out
FROM traders
JOIN counter_in ON traders.trader_id = counter_in.counter_domain_id
JOIN counter_out ON traders.trader_id = counter_out.counter_domain_id
GROUP BY traders.trader_id, traders.domain
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Results:

```
trader_id   domain  today_in    today_out
1   bing.com    3   3
2   google.com  4   4
3   yahoo.com   4   4
4   msn.com     3   3
5   yandex.com  1   1
```

Comment: You're certian that the contents of the `counter_in` and `counter_out` tables differ? Please post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the other answer may be giving you some sort of Cartesian result thus duplicating results.  Take your traders and join to distinct sub-query counts from respective in / out tables.

```
SELECT
      TT.trader_id,
      TT.Domain,
      TIN.InCount,
      TOUT.OutCount
   FROM 
      TableTraders TT

         LEFT Join ( select Trader_ID, count(*) as InCount
                   from TableIn
                   group by Trader_ID ) TIN
            on TT.Trader_ID = TIN.Trader_ID

         LEFT Join ( select Trader_ID, count(*) as InCount
                   from TableOut
                   group by Trader_ID ) TOUT
            on TT.Trader_ID = TOUT.Trader_ID
```

If you want it by DISTINCT IP address per in/out, just change

```
COUNT(*) 
to
COUNT( Distinct IP )
```

Comment: hi, see my edit in my post, have still some trouble, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  TableTraders.trader_id,
  TableTraders.Domain,
  COUNT(TableIn.trader_id) AS in_count,
  COUNT(TableOut.trader_id) AS out_count
FROM TableTraders 
  JOIN TableIn ON TableTraders.trader_id = TableIn.trader_id
  JOIN TableOut ON TableTraders.trader_id = TableOut.trader_id
GROUP BY TableTraders.trader_id, TableTraders.Domain
```

Not certain what your table names are from your example above, since they contain spaces.  Substitute the correct table names.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, im getting duplicate results, this happens also at my queries :(

`trader_id  domain  today_in  today_out`
`1  bing.com  3  3`
`2  google.com  4  4`
`3  yahoo.com  4  4`
`4  msn.com  3  3`
`5  yandex.com1  1  1`

Comment: @Plob post the query you ran, as an edit to your question above.

Comment: if i make the query separate one by one, it works, counted right. in one query it dont works, no clue what i do wrong.